# Delete Files Older than (x) Days?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

What's a good Windows command line option for deleting all files in a given folder older than (n) days?

Also note there may be many thousands of these files, so `forfiles` with a shell to `cmd` is not a great idea here.. unless you like spawning thousands of command shells. I consider that a pretty nasty hack, so let's see if we can do better!

Ideally, something built into (or easily installable into) Windows Server 2008.

Comment: A new method based in a .BAT file that use internal CMD.EXE commands only has been posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746778/ms-dos-batch-delete-old-files-in-directory/9747065#9747065

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I looked around a bit more and [found a powershell way](http://web.archive.org/web/20121213095648/http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/12/13/hey-powershell-guy-how-can-i-delete-files-that-are-a-specified-number-of-hours-old.aspx):

Delete all files more than 8 days old from the specified folder (with preview)

```
dir |? {$_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-8)} | del -whatif
```

(remove the -whatif to make it happen)

Comment: To confirm, does this permanently delete the files or recycle them?

Comment: Ops too hard for memorize!!i love powershell but i think better way is using [robocopy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6149776/1275574)

Answer (score 7):

Love Jeff's PowerShell command, but for an alternative vbs solution for Windows machines without PowerShell you could try the following.

Save as `<filename>.vbs` and execute:

```
<filename>.vbs <target_dir> <NoDaysSinceModified> [Action]
```

The third parameter, `[Action]` is optional.  Without it the files older than `<NoDaysSinceModified>` will be listed.  With it set as `D` it will delete files older than `<NoDaysSinceModified>`

**Example**

```
PurgeOldFiles.vbs "c:\Log Files" 8
```

will **list** all files in `c:\Log Files` older than 8 days old

```
PurgeOldFiles.vbs "c:\Log Files" 8 D
```

will **delete** all files in `c:\Log Files` older than 8 days old

note: this is a modified version of  Haidong Ji's script on [SQLServerCentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/usingvbscripttoautomatetasks/1171/)

```vbs
Option Explicit
on error resume next
    Dim oFSO
    Dim sDirectoryPath
    Dim oFolder
    Dim oFileCollection
    Dim oFile
    Dim iDaysOld
    Dim fAction

    sDirectoryPath = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
    iDaysOld = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
    fAction = WScript.Arguments.Item(2)
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sDirectoryPath)
    set oFileCollection = oFolder.Files

If UCase(fAction) = "D" Then
'Walk through each file in this folder collection. 
'If it is older than iDaysOld, then delete it.
    For each oFile in oFileCollection
        If oFile.DateLastModified < (Date() - iDaysOld) Then
            oFile.Delete(True)
        End If
    Next
else
'Displays Each file in the dir older than iDaysOld
    For each oFile in oFileCollection
        If oFile.DateLastModified < (Date() - iDaysOld) Then
            Wscript.Echo oFile.Name & " " & oFile.DateLastModified
        End If
    Next
End If


'Clean up
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oFileCollection = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set fAction = Nothing
```

Comment: I use something like this to delete old web server logs.  Has worked out pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

Not really command line, but I like using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) as a C# scripting host:
(which just gave me an idea for a command line C# scripting thingie à la vbs files)

```
var files = from f in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\temp", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            where File.GetLastWriteTime(f) < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-8)
            select f;

foreach(var f in files)
    File.Delete(f);
```

Comment: Linq is really awesome, I wish the would bring in to PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this http://sourceforge.net/projects/delold as this is what I use.

simple but works. **delold -d 14** Deletes files older that 14 days in the current folder.

Answer (score 3):

Something similar can be achieved with cygwin's (or other alternative) "find" command. But this would require you to install cygwin or have the portable version at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative I used to use before powershell:

http://lifehacker.com/133190/geek-to-live--hard-drive-janitor

Answer (score 2):

I use autoIT to accomplish this on my systems. I like that you can compile .au3 files to exe easily. Not as easy to introduce a security flaw as it is with a bat file anyone can edit.